# sp 2010: global navigation fly out does not work on "special pages" like recycle bin or site setting page

Tags: master-page, global-navigation

We modified the master page of our SP 2010 to show multiple levels of navigation by changing the 
`<SharePoint:AspMenu>` tag's `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` attribute and this works fine on every page except "site settings page" , "recycle bin" , "people and groups" etc.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The master page needs to be applied for both *Site Master Page* and *System Master Page* in order to have it applied to both - your publishing pages and the administrative pages, which include e.g. lists, recycle bin, settings page.